# grepl to search strings containing more than 2 paterns than includes parenthesis in R

Tags: grepl

Good afternoon,
I want to search for a string that contains two times the pattern "1)2"

I tried:
grepl('(1.+\).+2){2}', variable, fixed=TRUE)

Thank you very much in advance¡¡¡¡

Comment: Hello! The fixed = TRUE argument overrides the use of regular expressions. You are not searching for "1)2", you are searching for "(1.+\).+2){2}" as is.

Comment: Thank you Santiago for helping me. I tried grepl("(1.+).+2){2}", rownames(coef_1)) but it does not work either.

Comment: This works, in case somebody needs it  grepl(rex(at_least(group("1)2", anything),2))

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
> grepl(".*1\\)2.*1\\)2.*", c("bla1)2bla", "bla1)2blabla1)2bla", "blablabla"))
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```